# Converting .ui to .py with pyuic5?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

When I convert a .ui file in QtDesigner to a .py file, the format changes and it runs differently.
When I run it in QtDesigner it looks like a normal page but once I convert it to a .py file and run it, the edges are cut off and I cannot see half the buttons/labels. Even once I expand the screen that has opened the labels are cut off and only half visible.
Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

Comment: You're probably not using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html) (and you should).

Comment: I am using layout managers and spacers and setting the size I want it to be, but it is still not working

Comment: Then please [edit] your question with a [mre] of the UI file.

Comment: It's not really possible for me to do this as the file that makes the UI what it is is very long and cannot be made in a shorter way (it will change the format of the UI which defeats the purpose of what I am asking)

Comment: Sorry, but without any reference we cannot really help you. Be aware that: 1. layouts must be *set* on widget container, not added by drag and drop from the "widget box" of Designer, which is done by right clicking on an empty area of the widget container and selecting the proper option from the "Lay out" submenu (see [Using layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html); 2. QLabels using with word wrap have known [layout issues](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#layout-issues) that can only solved as a per-case basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You firstly need to correctly set the layout and widgets inside them, in a way that the size of each object is guaranteed when moving to the code.

Try to watch this tutorial, I found it very useful!

[Qt Designer - create application GUI (DESIGN APPLICATION LAYOUT) - part 02](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq89VPwFMOY)

And then you need to just import the .ui file as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import uic

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi("NameofYourFile.ui",self)
    self.show()
```